# How to do conditional groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, grouping, sequence

I'm working with the *AMI transcriptions* dataset ([link](https://groups.inf.ed.ac.uk/ami/corpus/transcription.shtml)) and converted the Words files into dataframes. Example of dataframe:

| index | speaker | word_id | word | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | E | 0 | 'Kay | 3.34 | 3.88 |
| 1 | E | 1 | . | 3.88 | 3.88 |
| 2 | A | 0 | Okay | 5.57 | 5.94 |
| 3 | E | 2 | Gosh | 5.6 | 6.01 |
| 4 | A | 1 | . | 5.94 | 5.94 |
| 5 | E | 3 | . | 6.01 | 6.01 |
| 6 | E | 4 | 'Kay | 10.48 | 10.88 |
| 7 | E | 5 | . | 10.88 | 10.88 |
| 8 | A | 2 | Does | 11.09 | 11.25 |
| 9 | A | 3 | anyone | 11.25 | 11.5 |
| 10 | A | 4 | want | 11.5 | 11.65 |
| 11 | A | 5 | to | 11.65 | 11.71 |
| 12 | A | 6 | see | 11.71 | 12.15 |
| 13 | A | 7 | uh | 12.15 | 12.42 |
| 14 | A | 8 | Steve's | 12.42 | 12.94 |
| 15 | A | 9 | feedback | 12.94 | 13.5 |
| 16 | A | 10 | from | 13.5 | 13.71 |
| 17 | A | 11 | the | 13.71 | 14.73 |
| 18 | A | 12 | specification | 14.73 | 15.53 |
| 19 | A | 13 | ? | 15.53 | 15.53 |
| 20 | E | 6 | Is | 16.77 | 16.94 |
| 21 | E | 7 | there | 16.94 | 17.04 |
| 22 | E | 8 | much | 17.04 | 17.25 |
| 23 | D | 0 | I | 17.08 | 17.34 |
| 24 | E | 9 | more | 17.25 | 17.53 |
| 25 | D | 1 | I | 17.34 | 17.47 |
| 26 | D | 2 | dry-read | 17.47 | 17.92 |
| 27 | E | 10 | in | 17.53 | 17.63 |
| 28 | E | 11 | it | 17.63 | 17.73 |
| 29 | E | 12 | than | 17.73 | 17.88 |
| 30 | E | 13 | he | 17.88 | 18.0 |

I define an utterance as follows: a list (sequence) of words by the same speaker, in which each consecutive words are spaced by no more than 0.5 seconds. Spacing between two consecutive words A, B is defined as the delta between the end time of A and the start time of B.

So for example, in the above data, we have the 7 utterances:

1. ['Kay, .] by speaker E (at indices 0, 1)
2. [Okay, .] by speaker A (at indices 2, 4)
3. [Gosh, .] by speaker E (at indices 3, 5)
4. [Kay, .] by speaker E (at indices 6, 7)
5. [Does, anyone, want, to, see, uh, Steve's, ..., ?] by speaker A (at indices 8-19)
6. [Is, there, much, more, in, it, than, he] by Speaker E (at indices 21-22, 24, 27-30)
7. [I, I, dry-read] by speaker D (at indices 23, 25-26)

My goal is to extract the utterances as shown above - by creating a list of words representing each utterance, and indicating the speaker of that utterance. In addition, I need to indicate whether there was any cross-talk during the utterance. Utterances with continuous indicies are those that have no cross-talk. In the above example, these are 1, 4 and 5.

I tried several directions but didn't find how to perform the grouping correctly.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It would be nice if u could provide code to reproduce above dataframe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one was quite tricky but fun to do :

We can start by groupby `shift` for each `speaker` :

```py
>>> df['end_time_shifted'] = df.groupby('speaker')['end_time'].shift(1)
>>> df
    speaker     word_id     word            start_time  end_time    end_time_shifted
0   E           0           'Kay            3.34        3.88        NaN
1   E           1           .               3.88        3.88        3.88
2   A           0           Okay            5.57        5.94        NaN
3   E           2           Gosh            5.60        6.01        3.88
4   A           1           .               5.94        5.94        5.94
5   E           3           .               6.01        6.01        6.01
6   E           4           'Kay            10.48       10.88       6.01
7   E           5           .               10.88       10.88       10.88
8   A           2           Does            11.09       11.25       5.94
9   A           3           anyone          11.25       11.50       11.25
10  A           4           want            11.50       11.65       11.50
11  A           5           to              11.65       11.71       11.65
12  A           6           see             11.71       12.15       11.71
13  A           7           uh              12.15       12.42       12.15
14  A           8           Steve's         12.42       12.94       12.42
15  A           9           feedback        12.94       13.50       12.94
16  A           10          from            13.50       13.71       13.50
17  A           11          the             13.71       14.73       13.71
18  A           12          specification   14.73       15.53       14.73
19  A           13          ?               15.53       15.53       15.53
20  E           6           Is              16.77       16.94       10.88
21  E           7           there           16.94       17.04       16.94
22  E           8           much            17.04       17.25       17.04
23  D           0           I               17.08       17.34       NaN
24  E           9           more            17.25       17.53       17.25
25  D           1           I               17.34       17.47       17.34
26  D           2           dry-read        17.47       17.92       17.47
27  E           10          in              17.53       17.63       17.53
28  E           11          it              17.63       17.73       17.63
29  E           12          than            17.73       17.88       17.73
30  E           13          he              17.88       18.00       17.88
```

Then, we compute the `time_delta` :

```py
>>> df['time_delta'] = df['end_time'] - df['end_time_shifted']
>>> df = df.fillna(0)
>>> df
    speaker     word_id     word            start_time  end_time    end_time_shifted    time_delta
0   E           0           'Kay            3.34        3.88        0.00                0.00
1   E           1           .               3.88        3.88        3.88                0.00
2   A           0           Okay            5.57        5.94        0.00                0.00
3   E           2           Gosh            5.60        6.01        3.88                1.72
4   A           1           .               5.94        5.94        5.94                0.00
5   E           3           .               6.01        6.01        6.01                0.00
6   E           4           'Kay            10.48       10.88       6.01                4.47
7   E           5           .               10.88       10.88       10.88               0.00
8   A           2           Does            11.09       11.25       5.94                5.15
9   A           3           anyone          11.25       11.50       11.25               0.00
10  A           4           want            11.50       11.65       11.50               0.00
11  A           5           to              11.65       11.71       11.65               0.00
12  A           6           see             11.71       12.15       11.71               0.00
13  A           7           uh              12.15       12.42       12.15               0.00
14  A           8           Steve's         12.42       12.94       12.42               0.00
15  A           9           feedback        12.94       13.50       12.94               0.00
16  A           10          from            13.50       13.71       13.50               0.00
17  A           11          the             13.71       14.73       13.71               0.00
18  A           12          specification   14.73       15.53       14.73               0.00
19  A           13          ?               15.53       15.53       15.53               0.00
20  E           6           Is              16.77       16.94       10.88               5.89
21  E           7           there           16.94       17.04       16.94               0.00
22  E           8           much            17.04       17.25       17.04               0.00
23  D           0           I               17.08       17.34       0.00                0.00
24  E           9           more            17.25       17.53       17.25               0.00
25  D           1           I               17.34       17.47       17.34               0.00
26  D           2           dry-read        17.47       17.92       17.47               0.00
27  E           10          in              17.53       17.63       17.53               0.00
28  E           11          it              17.63       17.73       17.63               0.00
29  E           12          than            17.73       17.88       17.73               0.00
30  E           13          he              17.88       18.00       17.88               0.00
```

Next, we mark by `1` or `0` if the word belong to the `next_utterance` given the contraint `time_delta<=0.5` :

```py
>>> df.loc[df.time_delta <= 0.5, 'next_utterance'] = 0 
>>> df.loc[df.time_delta > 0.5, 'next_utterance'] = 1
>>> df
    speaker     word_id     word            start_time  end_time    end_time_shifted    time_delta  next_utterance
0   E           0           'Kay            3.34        3.88        0.00                0.00        0.0
1   E           1           .               3.88        3.88        3.88                0.00        0.0
2   A           0           Okay            5.57        5.94        0.00                0.00        0.0
3   E           2           Gosh            5.60        6.01        3.88                1.72        1.0
4   A           1           .               5.94        5.94        5.94                0.00        0.0
5   E           3           .               6.01        6.01        6.01                0.00        0.0
6   E           4           'Kay            10.48       10.88       6.01                4.47        1.0
7   E           5           .               10.88       10.88       10.88               0.00        0.0
8   A           2           Does            11.09       11.25       5.94                5.15        1.0
9   A           3           anyone          11.25       11.50       11.25               0.00        0.0
10  A           4           want            11.50       11.65       11.50               0.00        0.0
11  A           5           to              11.65       11.71       11.65               0.00        0.0
12  A           6           see             11.71       12.15       11.71               0.00        0.0
13  A           7           uh              12.15       12.42       12.15               0.00        0.0
14  A           8           Steve's         12.42       12.94       12.42               0.00        0.0
15  A           9           feedback        12.94       13.50       12.94               0.00        0.0
16  A           10          from            13.50       13.71       13.50               0.00        0.0
17  A           11          the             13.71       14.73       13.71               0.00        0.0
18  A           12          specification   14.73       15.53       14.73               0.00        0.0
19  A           13          ?               15.53       15.53       15.53               0.00        0.0
20  E           6           Is              16.77       16.94       10.88               5.89        1.0
21  E           7           there           16.94       17.04       16.94               0.00        0.0
22  E           8           much            17.04       17.25       17.04               0.00        0.0
23  D           0           I               17.08       17.34       0.00                0.00        0.0
24  E           9           more            17.25       17.53       17.25               0.00        0.0
25  D           1           I               17.34       17.47       17.34               0.00        0.0
26  D           2           dry-read        17.47       17.92       17.47               0.00        0.0
27  E           10          in              17.53       17.63       17.53               0.00        0.0
28  E           11          it              17.63       17.73       17.63               0.00        0.0
29  E           12          than            17.73       17.88       17.73               0.00        0.0
30  E           13          he              17.88       18.00       17.88               0.00        0.0
```

Now, we can use `cumsum` by `speaker` to build the desired lists in the next step :

```py
>>> df['cumsum_by_group'] = df.groupby(['speaker'])['next_utterance'].cumsum()
>>> df
    speaker     word_id     word            start_time  end_time    end_time_shifted    time_delta  next_utterance  cumsum_by_group
0   E           0           'Kay            3.34        3.88        0.00                0.00        0.0             0.0
1   E           1           .               3.88        3.88        3.88                0.00        0.0             0.0
2   A           0           Okay            5.57        5.94        0.00                0.00        0.0             0.0
3   E           2           Gosh            5.60        6.01        3.88                1.72        1.0             1.0
4   A           1           .               5.94        5.94        5.94                0.00        0.0             0.0
5   E           3           .               6.01        6.01        6.01                0.00        0.0             1.0
6   E           4           'Kay            10.48       10.88       6.01                4.47        1.0             2.0
7   E           5           .               10.88       10.88       10.88               0.00        0.0             2.0
8   A           2           Does            11.09       11.25       5.94                5.15        1.0             1.0
9   A           3           anyone          11.25       11.50       11.25               0.00        0.0             1.0
10  A           4           want            11.50       11.65       11.50               0.00        0.0             1.0
11  A           5           to              11.65       11.71       11.65               0.00        0.0             1.0
12  A           6           see             11.71       12.15       11.71               0.00        0.0             1.0
13  A           7           uh              12.15       12.42       12.15               0.00        0.0             1.0
14  A           8           Steve's         12.42       12.94       12.42               0.00        0.0             1.0
15  A           9           feedback        12.94       13.50       12.94               0.00        0.0             1.0
16  A           10          from            13.50       13.71       13.50               0.00        0.0             1.0
17  A           11          the             13.71       14.73       13.71               0.00        0.0             1.0
18  A           12          specification   14.73       15.53       14.73               0.00        0.0             1.0
19  A           13          ?               15.53       15.53       15.53               0.00        0.0             1.0
20  E           6           Is              16.77       16.94       10.88               5.89        1.0             3.0
21  E           7           there           16.94       17.04       16.94               0.00        0.0             3.0
22  E           8           much            17.04       17.25       17.04               0.00        0.0             3.0
23  D           0           I               17.08       17.34       0.00                0.00        0.0             0.0
24  E           9           more            17.25       17.53       17.25               0.00        0.0             3.0
25  D           1           I               17.34       17.47       17.34               0.00        0.0             0.0
26  D           2           dry-read        17.47       17.92       17.47               0.00        0.0             0.0
27  E           10          in              17.53       17.63       17.53               0.00        0.0             3.0
28  E           11          it              17.63       17.73       17.63               0.00        0.0             3.0
29  E           12          than            17.73       17.88       17.73               0.00        0.0             3.0
30  E           13          he              17.88       18.00       17.88               0.00        0.0             3.0
```

To finish, we run a `groupby` on `speaker` and `cumsum_by_group` to produce the lists as expected :

```py
>>> df_word = df.groupby(['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group'])['word'].apply(list).to_frame().reset_index()
>>> df_word 
    speaker     cumsum_by_group     word
0   A           0.0                 [Okay, .]
1   A           1.0                 [Does, anyone, want, to, see, uh, Steve's, fee...
2   D           0.0                 [I, I, dry-read]
3   E           0.0                 ['Kay, .]
4   E           1.0                 [Gosh, .]
5   E           2.0                 ['Kay, .]
6   E           3.0                 [Is, there, much, more, in, it, than, he]
```

To know if the `utterance` is clean or not as asked in commentary you can do the following :

```py
>>> df_indice = df.groupby(['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group'])['index'].apply(list).to_frame().reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'indice'})
>>> df_indice
    speaker     cumsum_by_group     indice
0   A           0.0                 [2, 4]
1   A           1.0                 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
2   D           0.0                 [23, 25, 26]
3   E           0.0                 [0, 1]
4   E           1.0                 [3, 5]
5   E           2.0                 [6, 7]
6   E           3.0                 [20, 21, 22, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

We set a `check_continuity` function like so :

```py
>>> def check_continuity(df):
...     my_list = df['indice']
...     return all(a+1==b for a, b in zip(my_list, my_list[1:]))
            
>>> df_indice["is_clean"] = df_indice.apply(check_continuity, axis=1)
>>> df_indice
    speaker     cumsum_by_group     indice                                          is_clean
0   A           0.0                 [2, 4]                                          False
1   A           1.0                 [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  True
2   D           0.0                 [23, 25, 26]                                    False
3   E           0.0                 [0, 1]                                          True
4   E           1.0                 [3, 5]                                          False
5   E           2.0                 [6, 7]                                          True
6   E           3.0                 [20, 21, 22, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30]                False
```

By mergin the two `DataFrames`, you get the final expected result :

```py
>>> df = pd.merge(df_word,
...               df_indice,
...               how='left',
...               left_on=['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group'],
...               right_on=['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group'])
>>> df
    speaker     cumsum_by_group     word                                                indice                                          is_clean
0   A           0.0                 [Okay, .]                                           [2, 4]                                          False
1   A           1.0                 [Does, anyone, want, to, see, uh, Steve's, fee...   [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]  True
2   D           0.0                 [I, I, dry-read]                                    [23, 25, 26]                                    False
3   E           0.0                 ['Kay, .]                                           [0, 1]                                          True
4   E           1.0                 [Gosh, .]                                           [3, 5]                                          False
5   E           2.0                 ['Kay, .]                                           [6, 7]                                          True
6   E           3.0                 [Is, there, much, more, in, it, than, he]           [20, 21, 22, 24, 27, 28, 29, 30]                False
```

Comment: Hi @tlental, thanks for your help! I think the utterances you got do not match the ones I expected to get. For example, you have an utterance [feedback, from] but it should be part of the previous utterance and not a separate one. In fact we should have an utterance like utterance 5 in my question. 
I think the error could be because you do: 
>>> df['time_delta'] = df['end_time'] - df['end_time_shifted']
instead of 
>>> df['time_delta'] = df['start_time'] - df['end_time_shifted']
but I'm not sure that this is the whole issue.

Comment: @Assaf, you are right : I updated the answer with your suggestion. Does this answer your question ?

Comment: yes, i tried it as well and it looks good. The only remaining issue is how to indicate (in a new column) whether an utterance is a clean one or not. A clean utterance is an utterance in which the indicies of words are continuous, e.g [7, 8, 9] but not [7, 9].

Comment: As requested in your comment I added a new column indicating if the utterance is clean or not. Does it validate everything you asked ?

Comment: Many thanks, it looks great. I learned some new tricks here, especially the one with the cumsum, which makes it easy to define a groupby condition that separates the utterances of the same person. The indication of clean utterances is also nice, although I might have implemented the check_continuity function in a different way using np.diff and np.max). Just for clarification, I described the need for indication of clean utterances already in the question (it wasn't introduced in the comments).

Comment: Strangely enough, I get an error when running: 
df.groupby(['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group'])['index']

{KeyError}'Column not found: index'

I'm using pandas 1.3.3

Comment: I switched to:  df_indice = pd.Series(df.groupby(['speaker', 'cumsum_by_group']).indices)  and then I needed to set the names of the columns manually. Probably there's a more elegant solution.